# DokuWiki LDAP can't see any groups

Tags: ldap, dokuwiki

We have just changed our domain after protracted name change (the name actually happened two years ago!) and our DokuWiki installation has stopped being able to see any groups and memberships.

The config has been updated to reflect the new server and DCs and login is working correctly, it is only the groups that aren't working.

```
$conf['auth']['ldap']['server'] = 'ldap://MYDC.mydomain.co.uk:389';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['binddn'] = '%{user}@mydomain.co.uk';

$conf['auth']['ldap']['usertree'] = 'dc=mydomain,dc=co,dc=uk';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['userfilter'] = '(userPrincipalName=%{user}@mydomain.co.uk)';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['mapping']['name'] = 'displayname';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['mapping']['grps'] = 'array(\'memberof\' => \'/CN=(.+?),/i\')';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['grouptree'] = 'dc=mydomain,dc=co,dc=uk';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['groupfilter'] = '(&(cn=*)(Member=%{dn})(objectClass=group))';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['referrals'] = '0';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['version'] = '3';
$conf['auth']['ldap']['debug'] = 1;
```

Obviously I have edited the doain name there, but for the life of me I can't see what's wrong here, It all worked fine yesterday on the old domain.

I should also state that this is an old version of DokuWiki that for various reasons I can't actually update.

The debug line gives me a "ldap search: success" line, but if I add "?do=check" onto any url within the system I get "You are part of the groups"...... and nothing, it can't see any groups.

It's a massive pain as we have a pretty intricate ACL setup for the site, so it's not like I can just throw it open to all.

If anyone has any suggestions, no matter how obvious, please pass them on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by changing the dokuwiki authentication plugin that was used, the 'authad' is more simple to use and just works with what I'm doing.

As a side bonus it also means that I have finally been able to get the install upgraded to the current version.